# Array size allocation error

Tags: c++, arrays, size

I have been getting an error in this code pasted below.
It says:

1.Expression must have a constant value.

2.Expression did not evaluate to a constant

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



int main() 
{

    string ko = "flip";
    int kosize = ko.size();
    char arra[kosize] = { 1,3,2 };
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    return 0;
}
```

So how do I assign an array based on the size of a string?

Comment: Generally speaking in C++, you don't.  You'd use e.g. a `std::vector`.

Comment: In C++, a declaration like `int arr[kosize]` requires `kosize` to be a compile time constant.   `kosize` is a variable i.e. its value is determined at run time.  Hence the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how do I assign an array based on the size of a string?

You can use dynamically allocated array, such as:

```
char* arra = new char[kosize];
arra[0] = 1;
arra[1] = 3;
arra[2] = 2;
```

However, using dynamically allocated memory like that puts the burden of managing that memory on you. You have to make sure that you release the memory.
It will be better to use a `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<char> arra(kosize);
arra[0] = 1;
arra[1] = 3;
arra[2] = 2;
```

Comment: @Curious, my intention was to create a `vector` of the given size explicitly.

Comment:  works for me, I just thought the `initializer_list` would make it easier for OP to make the decision to switch to `std::vector`